# sort-columns, but with a stable sort

Tags: sorting, column

How can I perform the equivalent of `M-x sort-columns` with a stable sort?

For example, let's say my text is:

```
a 99
b 98
b 97
a 96
a 95
b 94
a 93
b 92
c 91
...
```

And I want to perform a stable sort against the first column.

With sort-columns I would put mark at the beginning of the buffer, put point in the last line just after the first column, and `M-x sort-columns RET`.

My problem is that this sort is not stable.  The output is:

```
a 93
a 95
a 96
a 99
b 92
b 94
b 97
b 98
c 91
```

Whereas I need to keep the line order for each first column:

```
a 99
a 96
a 95
a 93
b 98
b 97
b 94
b 92
c 91
```

How could I do that?  Is there a hidden option in `sort-columns`?  Or is some Elisp necessary?  I know `sort --stable` could do the trick but I want a solution that works on Windows where the `sort` command-line tool is absent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that `sort-fields` does what you want. At least it does so with the example text you show.

See also the Elisp manual, node [Sorting](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sorting.html).

Comment: "sort-fields" doesn't seem documented as being a stable sort, though in practice it looks like it is.  So it might stop being stable in the next Emacs releases?

Comment: Yes, presumably so. But it's been the way it is for many decades. Please consider sending an enhancement request to document that it is a stable sort (and thus have Emacs commit to that), using `M-x report-emacs-bug`.